# How to pronounce words that end in consonant clusters like '-nds' or '-ths'?

Tags: pronunciation, british-english, consonant-clusters

I want to know how to pronounce words that end in consonant clusters such as '-nds' (e.g. *sounds*), '-th' (e.g. *fifth, sixth*), and 'ths' (e.g. *clothes*).

Comment: You can find audio files and phonetic transcriptions of almost any word here: www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/ The case of fifth is interesting, because it can be pronounced either as [fɪfθ] or as [fɪθ].

Answer (score 5):

English speakers regularly simplify certain clusters in English. This is usually not random, but relies on various rules in the language. In particular:

1. the cluster /ndz/ as found in *sounds, finds, pounds, friends, grinds* and so forth can be reduced to /nz/:

   - /saʊnz,  faɪnz, paʊnz, frenz, graɪnz/

Clusters with the 'th' sounds /θ/ or /ð/ very often get reduced at the ends of words too. For example, *fifth* is often pronounced /fɪθ/ and sixth /sɪkθ/. The word *clothes* is more often than not pronounced the same as *close* (meaning *shut*): /kləʊz/.

Comment: It's a well-known fact (although one that many native English speakers refuse to believe at first) that there is usually no difference between *prince* and *prints* – /ns/ and /nts/ – in English pronunciation. The clusters /nz/ and /ndz/ are the voiced analogs of these, and the difference between *fines* and *finds* is quite small, if it exists at all.

Comment: @PeterShor Yes, in fact there's no difference if there's alvelor elosion of /d/ between *fines* and *finds* - but the very interesting *prince*, *prints* thing doesn't really happen because of elision - it's the other way round it's the epenthesis of /t/ into *prince* that makes them the same. The /n/ in /ndz/ is a bit of a red herring btw, the only requirement there is that that sound is voiced ... I wrote a proper description here [alveolar plosive elision](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/199077/why-do-people-often-say-hambag-for-handbag)!

Comment: @PeterShor It's interesting that we never believe stuff about phonetics/phonology till we really start studying and listening ... It doesn't really work that way with grammar for instance!